# fortran: command_argument_COUNT() return -1

Tags: fortran, fortran90, netcdf

I use `command_argument_COUNT()` to return number of command line arguments; however, such function always return `-1`, which is supposed to be a non-negative value?

**What are the possible causes for `-1`?**

I use gfortran v6.1.0.

---

**Edit 1:**

Since this program is linked with many other subroutines, a whole test code is difficult to be provided here.

I also tried to test `command_argument_COUNT()` solely, which worked as supposed.
The issue occurred when I linked it with some other subroutines.

So, at the moment, I'm guessing if some old pieces (in F77) are causing the issues. Would that be possible?

---

**Edit 2:**

Just resolved this issue, which turned out to be the conflicts in different netcdf libraries of my system. When I cleaned them and re-set netcdf up, such issues were gone.

Comment: What does calling `get_command` return? That may give a hint.Make sure to check the status too.

Comment: both `command_argument_COUNT()` and `get_command_argument` are called in the main program.

Comment: and `get_command` returns nothing: just a blank line.

Comment: I just tried to specify status, which was returned as 0 meaning successful. But apparently the command line arguments following main.exe were ignored somehow.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with a simple program that  just calls `command_argument_COUNT()`?  Are you actually invoking the program from a command line? what system?

Comment: It is hard to provide a minimal case, which I indeed would like to do. And as I added in the edits: the sole `command_argument_COUNT() ` case did work; but when the main program was linked with other subroutines, the program failed. So I'm wondering if anyone could provide any possibility that cause such failures.

Comment: @agentp, yes, I invoked the program from the terminal under Mac OS X 10.11.5. And the program was compiled with gfortran 6.1.

Comment: @francescalus, no, this program is executed sequentially.

Comment: hi folks, just resolved this issue, which turned out to be the conflicts in different netcdf libraries of my system. When I cleaned them and re-set netcdf up, such issues were gone. Thank you all!